# Confusion Matrix only considering predictions > threshold

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The output layer of my network is

```
model.add(Dense(2, activation=activations.softmax))
```

outputting a one hot encoded category prediction.

`model.predict` therefore returns n predictions like

```
[9.9584144e-01, 4.1585001e-03],
[7.5779420e-01, 2.4220583e-01],
...
```

I now not only want the full confusion matrix provided by sklearn through

```
metrics.confusion_matrix(y_TEST.argmax(axis=1), y_pred.argmax(axis=1), normalize='pred')
```

but I'd like to see how the confusion matrix looks only for the cases where the max prediction is larger than a given threshold.

Something like

```
metrics.confusion_matrix(y_TEST.argmax(axis=1), y_pred.argmax(axis=1), normalize='pred', 
                         min_confidence_threshold='0.9')
```

Does sklearn or any of the standard tools here provide a functionality like that?

If not, how would I filter two arrays (y_TEST, y_pred) based on a condition of one of the arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that can do this:

```py
def threshold_matrix(labels,probs,threshold=0):
    assert 0 <= threshold <= 1
    t_map = lambda x : 1 if tf.math.reduce_max(x) > threshold else 0
    thres = tf.map_fn(t_map, probs)

    pred  = tf.boolean_mask(tf.argmax(probs,1),thres)
    labs  = tf.boolean_mask(tf.cast(labels, tf.int64),thres)

    return tf.math.confusion_matrix(labs,pred)
```